# Intel® TinyCrypt: AES-128/CTR to encryption/decryption of 2D arrays

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, aes

I need to encrypt/decrypt 2D arrays (double pointers) using AES-128/CTR using [Intel TinyCrypt](https://github.com/01org/tinycrypt) (written in C). The following are two helper methods to simplify the library usage. Any comments would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```cpp
#include <tinycrypt/constants.h>
#include <tinycrypt/ctr_mode.h>
#include <tinycrypt/aes.h>

#define AES_128_KEY_LENGTH 16
#define AES_128_CTR_LENGTH 16

typedef struct aes_128_ctr_params_t{
  byte key[AES_128_KEY_LENGTH];
  byte ctr[AES_128_CTR_LENGTH];
} aes_128_ctr_params_t;

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline int32_t encrypt(uint8_t const * const * const plaintext,
                       uint8_t * const * const cihpertext,
                       size_t const height,
                       size_t const width,
                       aes_128_ctr_params_t params) {
  //TODO: Do some validation here!

  struct tc_aes_key_sched_struct sched;
  uint32_t result = TC_CRYPTO_SUCCESS;
  result = tc_aes128_set_encrypt_key(&sched, params.key);
  if (result != TC_CRYPTO_SUCCESS)
    return result;

  size_t const row_size_in_bytes = sizeof(uint8_t) * width;
  for (size_t row_index = 0; row_index < height; ++row_index) {
    result = tc_ctr_mode(cihpertext[row_index], row_size_in_bytes,
      plaintext[row_index], row_size_in_bytes, params.ctr, &sched);

    if (result != TC_CRYPTO_SUCCESS)
      return result;
  }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
inline int32_t decrypt(uint8_t const * const * const cihpertext,
                       uint8_t * const * const plaintext,
                       size_t const height,
                       size_t const width,
                       aes_128_ctr_params_t params) {
  //TODO: Do some validation here!

  struct tc_aes_key_sched_struct sched;
  uint32_t result = TC_CRYPTO_SUCCESS;
  result = tc_aes128_set_encrypt_key(&sched, params.key);
  if (result != TC_CRYPTO_SUCCESS)
    return result;

  size_t const row_size_in_bytes = sizeof(uint8_t) * width;
  for (size_t row_index = 0; row_index < height; ++row_index) {
    result = tc_ctr_mode(plaintext[row_index], row_size_in_bytes,
      cihpertext[row_index], row_size_in_bytes, params.ctr, &sched);

    if (result != TC_CRYPTO_SUCCESS)
      return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your code a bit dense and hard to read overall.

Your identifier names are compound words but all lower case.

```
plaintext
```

I prefer `plainText` others would prefer `plain_text` (and a lot of the code uses this second C like style). But either is preferable to your current style.

This seems redundant.

```
uint32_t result = TC_CRYPTO_SUCCESS;
result = tc_aes128_set_encrypt_key(&sched, params.key);
```

Just use one line:

```
uint32_t result = tc_aes128_set_encrypt_key(&sched, params.key);
```

Technically both functions exhibit undefined behavior (in C++ not sure about C). There is no return on successful completion.

```
    if (result != TC_CRYPTO_SUCCESS)
      return result;
  }
  // Add the following line
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly excited about the way you've expressed the logic of your functions. At least IMO, it's written kind of like a collection of special cases instead of applying general rules. I think I'd prefer something closer to this:

```
inline int32_t decrypt(uint8_t const * const * const cihpertext,
    uint8_t * const * const plaintext,
    size_t const height,
    size_t const width,
    aes_128_ctr_params_t params) 
{
    struct tc_aes_key_sched_struct sched;
    auto const good = TC_CRYPTO_SUCCESS;

    uint32_t result = tc_aes128_set_encrypt_key(&sched, params.key);

    size_t const row_size_in_bytes = sizeof(uint8_t) * width;

    for (size_t row_index = 0; row_index < height && result == good; ++row_index) {
        result = tc_ctr_mode(plaintext[row_index], row_size_in_bytes,
            cihpertext[row_index], row_size_in_bytes, params.ctr, &sched);
    }
    return result;
}
```